# How do we send logo in footer and header of message body using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

I need to send logo of microsoft in header and footer section of message body using graph API. Previously we used smtp server with mailmessage and that supports Linkedresource with alternativeView. Now how do i need to set logo using graph API. Is there any supported similar type in graph api?
Please help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately natively you don't have any footer/header as part of Message body using Microsoft Graph API. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) about the message body. As a last option, you can consider [adding attachment (as inline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/attachment?view=graph-rest-1.0), but i am not sure it will help you. Being said that i remember a [related feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/15275559-office-365-rest-api-include-email-signature) been submitted in Microsoft Uservoice to support email signature (so that you can place your logo in it). Consider upvoting it, so that it can be implemented by Microsoft Graph team.